# Cannot correctly wrap element anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap an svg with an "a" element that's also a child of it's parent, but the loop isn't working correctly because all of the svg's are being wrapped with the very first link. I don't know why this is happening. Thanks!

I would link to turn this:

```
<li>
    Topic 1
    <svg></svg>
    <a href="link1"> </a>
</li>
```

Into This

```
<li>
   <a href="link1">
     Topic 1
     <svg></svg>
   </a>
</li>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("ul").each(function(){

          var link =  $(this).find('a').attr('href');
   $(this).find('svg').wrap("<a href=" + link + "></a>");

     });
 
});
```

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
}
ul li{
 width: 90px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul li:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Topic 1
            <svg></svg>
            <a href="link1"> </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            Topic 2
            <svg></svg>
            <a href="link2"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            Topic 3
            <svg></svg>
            <a href="link3"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            Topic4
            <svg></svg>
            <a href="link4"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't wrap an `<li>` with an anchor; it's invalid HTML. You're also looping via `.each()` on the `<ul>` when you don't need to. Iterate on the `<li>` instead

Comment: @j08691 please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop with `.each()` on the `<li>` not the `<ul>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(this).find('svg').wrap("<a href=" + link + "></a>");

  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  width: 90px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <ul>
    <li>
      Topic 1
      <svg></svg>
      <a href="link1"> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Topic 2
      <svg></svg>
      <a href="link2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Topic 3
      <svg></svg>
      <a href="link3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Topic4
      <svg></svg>
      <a href="link4"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through each 'li' within the 'ul';

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("ul li").each(function(){

          var link =  $(this).find('a').attr('href');
      $(this).find('svg').wrap("<a href=" + link + "></a>");

     });

});
```